# Why mongodb query to find documents with two values in array does not work?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find mongodb documents with array 'products' including **both** values 'value1' and 'value2'.

Why does the first query below work while the second one does not?

```
## First query: Correct

db.person.find(
    {
        $and: [
        { segment: /a/i },
        { products: { $elemMatch: { productType: /value1/i } } },
        { products: { $elemMatch: { productType: /value2/i } } }
        ]
    }
).count()

## Results: 474 (Correct)
```

---

```
## Second query: WRONG

db.person.find(
    {
        segment: /a/i,
        products: {
            $elemMatch: { productType: /value1/i },
            $elemMatch: { productType: /value2/i }
        }
    }
).count()

## Results: 698 (WRONG)
```

Comment: For first query, you are querying on **individual fields** inside the `products` object. For second query, you are querying on **whole object**, which will require exact match for whole `products` object.

Comment: Thanks! What does turn the 2nd case into a query on whole object? Just the presence of more than one key within 'products' ? Can you please point some reference on this subject?

Comment: Hope [this official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document) is useful for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend has found this answer on why the 2nd case does not work:

> To explain why you received only the result matching the second criteria: The objects inside each {} you pass to MongoDB are key/value pairs. Each key can only exist once per object. When you try to assign a value to the same key twice, the second assignment will override the first. In your case you assigned two different values to the key $elemMatch in the same object, so the first one was ignored. The query which actually arrived in MongoDB was just `find({'vitamins': {'$elemMatch': {'name': 'B7', 'state': 'free'}}}).`
>
> Whenever you need to apply the same operator to the same key twice, you need to use `$or` or `$and`.

Source: https://coderedirect.com/questions/343064/mongodb-multiple-elemmatch